# Unlimited tree view foreach and while at same table

Tags: laravel, for-loop, foreach, view, while-loop

I have this table

```
Schema::create('categorys', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('category_name',50);
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categorys');          
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and with this I get data as a tree like this one:

[image]

I have these two methods on my model:

```
public function get_parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','id','category_id');
}
public function get_sons()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category','id','category_id');
}
```

so in my blade I did this.

```
@foreach($categorys->where('category_id','=',null) as $category)
    <a>{{$category->category_name}}</a>
    @foreach($category->get_sons as $dd)
        <a>{{$dd->category_name}}</a>
        <br />
        @foreach($dd->get_sons as $cc)
            <a>{{$cc->category_name}}</a>
            <br />
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
    <br />
@endforeach
```

In this case it will just bring me three times sons. 
and sometimes it's 12 times and 15 times.

If I work like that I have to write 15 time `foreach` in my blade.
Is there is a way to write the `while` statement to just till there is no data without having to add `foreach` inside `foreach` inside `foreach` and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a blade partial to do this:

```
@foreach($categorys->where('category_id','=',null) as $category)
    @include('viewname.partial')
@endforeach
```

Create a partial.blade.php with:

```
<a>{{$category->category_name}}</a>
@foreach($category->get_sons as $c)
    @include('viewname.partial', [ 'category' => $c])
@endforeach
```

This will make a recursion and will stop when there are no results for all `get_sons`.